# preg_replace only OUTSIDE tags ? (... we're not talking full 'html parsing', just a bit of markdown)

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, markdown, markup

What is the easiest way of applying highlighting of some text excluding text within OCCASIONAL tags "<...>"?

**CLARIFICATION**: I want the existing tags PRESERVED!

```
$t = 
preg_replace(
  "/(markdown)/",
  "<strong>$1</strong>",
"This is essentially plain text apart from a few html tags generated with some
simplified markdown rules: <a href=markdown.html>[see here]</a>");
```

Which should display as:

"This is essentially plain text apart from a few html tags generated with some simplified **markdown** rules: [see here](http://www.markdown.com)"

... BUT NOT MESS UP the text inside the anchor tag (i.e. `<a href=markdown.html>` ).

I've heard the arguments of not parsing html with regular expressions, but here we're talking essentially about plain text except for minimal parsing of some markdown code.

Comment: Why not just search for all tags and replace them with a uniq id (or an auto incrementing number with a * at the start. Then run the mark down preg_replace, and then run an str_replace to put them all back.

Comment: In the output, why is markdown highlighted? Because it occured in the parameter of the `a` tag?

Comment: Related: [Highlight keywords in a paragraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081372/highlight-keywords-in-a-paragraph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this seems to work ok:

```
<?php
$item="markdown";
$t="This is essentially plain text apart from a few html tags generated 
with some simplified markdown rules: <a href=markdown.html>[see here]</a>";

//_____1. apply emphasis_____
$t = preg_replace("|($item)|","<strong>$1</strong>",$t);

// "This is essentially plain text apart from a few html tags generated 
// with some simplified <strong>markdown</strong> rules: <a href=
// <strong>markdown</strong>.html>[see here]</a>"

//_____2. remove emphasis if WITHIN opening and closing tag____
$t = preg_replace("|(<[^>]+?)(<strong>($item)</strong>)([^<]+?>)|","$1$3$4",$t);

// this preserves the text before ($1), after ($4) 
// and inside <strong>..</strong> ($2), but without the tags ($3)

// "This is essentially plain text apart from a few html tags generated
// with some simplified <strong>markdown</strong> rules: <a href=markdown.html>
// [see here]</a>"

?>
```

A string like `$item="odd|string"` would cause some problems, but I won't be using that kind of string anyway... (probably needs htmlentities(...) or the like...)

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string into *tag*‍/‍*no-tag* parts using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$parts = preg_split('/(<(?:[^"\'>]|"[^"<]*"|\'[^\'<]*\')*>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Then you can iterate the parts while skipping every even part (i.e. the *tag* parts) and apply your replacement on it:

```
for ($i=0, $n=count($parts); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $parts[$i] = preg_replace("/(markdown)/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $parts[$i]);
}
```

At the end put everything back together with [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$str = implode('', $parts);
```

But note that this is really not the best solution. You should better use a proper HTML parser like PHP’s DOM library. See for example these related questions:

- [Highlight keywords in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081372/highlight-keywords-in-a-paragraph)
- [Regex / DOMDocument - match and replace text not in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044812/regex-domdocument-match-and-replace-text-not-in-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

First replace any string after a tag, but force your string is after a tag:

`$t=preg_replace("|(>[^<]*)(markdown)|i",'$1<strong>$2</strong>',"<null>$t");`

Then delete your forced tag:

`$show=preg_replace("|<null>|",'',$show);`

Answer (score 0):

This regex should strip all HTML opening and closing tags: `/(<[.*?]>)+/`

You can use it with preg_replace like this:

```
$test = "Hello <strong>World!</strong>";
$regex = "/(<.*?>)+/";


$result = preg_replace($regex,"",$test);
```

Comment: I should have made it clearer: I want the existing tags preserved! (see edit above)

Comment: I'm sorry, im confused. You would want to highlight all the text that is not in a html element?

Answer (score 0):

You could split your string into an array at every '<' or '>' using `preg_split()`, then loop through that array and replace only in entries not beginning with an '>'. Afterwards you combine your array to an string using `implode()`.

Answer (score 0):

actually this is not very efficient, but it worked for me

```
$your_string = '...';

$search = 'markdown';
$left = '<strong>';
$right = '</strong>';

$left_Q = preg_quote($left, '#');
$right_Q = preg_quote($right, '#');
$search_Q = preg_quote($search, '#');
while(preg_match('#(>|^)[^<]*(?<!'.$left_Q.')'.$search_Q.'(?!'.$right_Q.')[^>]*(<|$)#isU', $your_string))
  $your_string = preg_replace('#(^[^<]*|>[^<]*)(?<!'.$left_Q.')('.$search_Q.')(?!'.$right_Q.')([^>]*<|[^>]*$)#isU', '${1}'.$left.'${2}'.$right.'${3}', $your_string);

echo $your_string;
```