# Error when str_replace in html code

Tags: php

I have a sample code html:

```
$text = '<img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" /> abc def ghi abc xyz';
echo str_replace('abc', 'has replace', $text);
```

when i echo result is in tag `<img/>` has replace '`abc`' to '`has replace`' => error

How to when run result is:

```
<img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" /> has replace def ghi has replace xyz
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_replace only OUTSIDE tags ? (... we're not talking full 'html parsing', just a bit of markdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603780/preg-replace-only-outside-tags-were-not-talking-full-html-parsing-jus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a ideas:

```
$k=0;
$arr = array();
$regex = '/(<img.*?\/>)/ism';
if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
   if(isset($tmp[0])) {             
      for($i = 0;$i < count($tmp[0]); $i++) {
         $arr[0][$k] = $tmp[0][$i];
         $arr[1][$k] = md5($tmp[0][$i]);
         $text = str_replace($arr[0][$k], $arr[1][$k], $text);
         $k++;
      }
   }
}
```

And then you can replace:

```
echo str_replace('abc', 'has replace', $text);
```

Result now is:
$text = '74d3ae3af91872413da1db45d88ddd4a abc def ghi abc xyz'; // img has been md5

Final you can:

```
for($i = 0;$i < $k; $i++) {
    $text   = str_replace($arr[1][$i], $arr[0][$i], $text);
}
```

Hope you will successful