# Unable to highlight words correctly inside a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to highlight some specific words inside a string.

For example:

```
$keyword='span';

$string='<span>Set color of the string inside span.</span>';
```

and using the following function:

```
$str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<span style='color:orange;'>$0</span>",$string);
```

Now, the problem is, it is highlighting 'span' keyword both of span tag and span inside string, but **I want to highlight "span" inside string only** not of span tag itself, but don't know how to do this.

And I want to do all of this **without using strip_tags**.

Comment: In your example, there is not "color" in your `style` attribute, but anyway I get the idea. With one regexp, it's going to be a pain. You would be better off sanitizing `$string` beforehand, i.e. extract what is between `<span></span>`, do you replacement, and then add back `<span>` and `</span>`.

Comment: i have edited my question please review it

Comment: Seems like a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603780/preg-replace-only-outside-tags-were-not-talking-full-html-parsing-jus

Comment: Why can't you (or won't you) use `strip_tags`? If you want the output to have tags on them it's not a problem - adding the tags back in is super easy. Sometimes it's easier to just delete something and replace it instead of changing it.

Comment: hi, please try this <?php $keyword='s'; $str='<span style="float:left;">Set color of the string inside left.</span>'; echo preg_replace("/($keyword)/i",'<span style="color:red;"> $0</span>',$str); ?>, in this case i just want to highlight the "s" character, but it is highlight "s" of span and style also, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
<?php

$keyword='span';

$str='<span>Set color of the string inside span.</span>';

echo preg_replace("/(?<!<|\/)$keyword/i",'<span style="color:red;">$0</span>',$str);
```

Comment: but how you would do this without using strip_tags, i don't want to remove any of tag from the html

Comment: @Insomania run the code and view source code in browser, all html tags are preserved.

Comment: hi, please try this <?php
$keyword='s';
$str='<span style="float:left;">Set color of the string inside left.</span>';
echo preg_replace("/($keyword)/i",'<span style="color:red;"> $0</span>',$str);
?>, in this case i just want to highlight the "s" character, but it is highlight "s" of span and style also, how to do this?

Comment: @Insomania try this, it will work for 's' 'span' also `/(?<!<|>|\/)s/ig`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93065/discussion-between-neel-ion-and-insomania).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are tring to parse HTML code. I would suggest to remove HTML tags, then parse plain text and then insert it to final html code.

```
$keyword='span';
$string='<span>Set color of the string inside span.</span>';
$string_notags = strip_tags($string); //remove html tags
echo "<span>".preg_replace("/(".$keyword.")/iu", "<span style=\"color:red\">$1</span>", $string_notags)."</span>";
```

Comment: but how you would do this without using strip_tags, i don't want to remove any of tag from the html

Answer (score 0):

I have two solution as per your code scenario. Hope both of these solutions will work for you

1. `$str = preg_replace("/^\s($keyword)[^>]/i","<span style='color:orange;'>$0</span>",$string);`
2. `$str = preg_replace("/[^<]($keyword)[^>]/i","<span style='color:orange;'>$0</span>",$string);`