# Highlighting Keyword in search results

Tags: php, mysql, replace

How do I highlight keywords in search result?

Here's an example of my code:

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

$keyword = 'racing';
$query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR description LIKE '%$keyword%'");

while($result = $query->fetch_object())
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo $result->title.'<br />';
    echo substr($result->description,'0','256');
    echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

In this code, the keyword is `racing`, so I would like all the `racing` in the search result highlighted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight keywords in a paragraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081372/highlight-keywords-in-a-paragraph)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace your keyword with a styled `<span>` containing the keyword.

```
$result->title = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i",'<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $result->title);
```

With `$keyword = "racing"` and a text "You know racing? It's awesome.", `$result->title` will be

> `You know <span class="highlight">racing</span>? It's awesome.`

Then you simply style the highlight class using CSS, something like

```css
.highlight { background-color: #ffa; }
```

.....